# Handlebars Each Outputting More than Records

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, sequelize.js

I am having issue with my handlebars each statement where the amount of HTML tags being outputted is much larger than the amount of records being displayed in my SQL query. All I have been able to identify in tests is that there doesn't appear to be an issue with my SQL query as it displays the exact count of records in the database and is not fanning out the data. This has left me to think that it might be something with my loop or object storing the SQL query information.

Here is the HTML being displayed:

[image: handlebars output]

Here is the HTML:

```
{{#each currentUsers}}
                <li>{{this.email}} ({{#with this.teams.[0]}}{{teamName}}{{else}}No Team{{/with}})|<a href="/app/settings/users/{{this.userId}}/team">Edit Team</a> {{#ifeq this.userId ../user.userId}} (Admin) {{else}}| <a href="/app/users/{{this.userId}}" id="user-delete-link">Delete</a>{{/ifeq}}</li>
            {{else}}
                <p>No additional users</p>
{{/each}}
```

Here is my Route:

```
appRoutes.route('/settings/users')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.User.find({
                where: {
                    organizationId: organization.organizationId
                }, attributes: ['userId', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
                include: [{ 
                    model: models.Team,
                    attributes: ['teamName']
                }]
            });
        }).then(function(currentUsers){
            res.render('pages/app/settings-users.hbs',{
                user: req.user,
                currentUsers: currentUsers
            });
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
            console.log(error);
        })
    });
```

**Here is the output of the SQL, which displays exactly one record as I expect:**

[image: SQL Output]

Finally the actual SQL:

```
SELECT `user`.*, `teams`.`team_id` AS `teams.teamId`, `teams`.`team_name` AS `teams.teamName`, `teams.member`.`member_id` AS `teams.member.memberId`, `teams.member`.`member_email` AS `teams.member.memberEmail`, `teams.member`.`organization_id` AS `teams.member.organizationId`, `teams.member`.`team_id` AS `teams.member.teamId`, `teams.member`.`user_id` AS `teams.member.userId`, `teams.member`.`created_at` AS `teams.member.created_at`, `teams.member`.`updated_at` AS `teams.member.updated_at`, `teams.member`.`organization_id` AS `teams.member.organization_id`, `teams.member`.`team_id` AS `teams.member.team_id`, `teams.member`.`user_id` AS `teams.member.user_id` FROM (SELECT `user`.`user_id` AS `userId`, `user`.`email`, `user`.`first_name` AS `firstName`, `user`.`last_name` AS `lastName` FROM `user` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`organization_id` = 2 LIMIT 1) AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN (`member` AS `teams.member` INNER JOIN `team` AS `teams` ON `teams`.`team_id` = `teams.member`.`team_id`) ON `user`.`userId` = `teams.member`.`user_id`;
```

Comment: Try to use `Model.findAll()` that always returns array of objects if there any data. `.find()` returns object if there one record and array if more

Comment: Thank you so much @TilekbekovYrysbek that was the exact answer I was looking for. Do you mind pasting this as an answer and I will approve and upvote? Very helpful and a simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Model.findAll()` that always returns array of objects if there any data. `.find()` returns object if there one record and array if more